# How can I deploy my Angular 8 app on Apache server on ubuntu 18?

Tags: angular, apache, ubuntu

How can I display my `dist` folder that has been created in windows using `ng build --prod`, in an Ubuntu 18 server using Apache?

Comment: Create  a virtual dir that points to that folder

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter on which operating system you compiled angular application, it's javascript that gets interpreted by the browser at the end. Therefore just paste the contents of dist folder into respectable Apache directory and you're good to go.

Comment: I have a problem with the images some do not load me